# How to check the value and type of a unknown var

Tags: php

I have a variable that can be int or bool, this is because the db from where im querying it change the variable type at some point from bool to int, where now 1 is true and 0 is false.

Since php is "delicate" with the '===' i like to ask if this is the correct why to know if that var is true:

```
if($wallet->locked === 1 || $wallet->locked === true)
```

I think in this way im asking for: is the type is int and one? or is the var type bool and true?

How will you approach this problem?

Comment: Just use `==`. Then both `1` and `true` are true.

Comment: `$wallet->locked = (boolean) $wallet->locked;`

Comment: if($wallet->locked){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is the correct way.

It indeed checks if the type is [integer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) and the value is `1`, or the type is [boolean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) and the value is `true`.

The expression `($x === 1 || $x === true)` will be false in every other case.

If you know your variable is an integer or boolean already, and you're okay with all integers other than `0` evaluating to `true`, then you can just use:

```
if($wallet->locked) {
```

Which will be true whenever the above expression is, but also for values like `-1, 2, 1000` or any other non-zero integer.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems to be perfect, but You can also use [gettype](http://php.net/gettype). After that You can check the return value with "integer" or "boolean". Depending on the result You can process the data the way You need it.

**solution #1**. If `$wallet` has the value of either `false` or `0`, then PHP will not bother to check its type (because `&&` operator is short-circuit in PHP):

```
$wallet = true;
//$wallet = 1;
if( $wallet && (gettype($wallet) == "integer" || gettype($wallet) == "boolean") )
{ echo "This value is either 'true and 1' OR it is '1 and an integer'"; }
else { echo "This value is not true"; }
```

**solution #2** (depending on what You want to achieve):

```
$wallet = 0;
//$wallet = 1; // $wallet = 25;
//$wallet = true;
//$wallet = false;
if($wallet)
{ echo "This value is true"; }
else { echo "This value is not true"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$wallet->locked = 1;
if($wallet->locked === true){
    echo 'true';
}else{
    echo 'false';
}
```

will produce:

```
false
```

and

```
$wallet->locked = 1;
if($wallet->locked == true){
    echo 'true';
}else{
    echo 'false';
}
```

will produce:

```
true
```

Let me know if that helps!